Lost phone & all notes (my book). Are they in Google Backup?
Wrote my life's memories on NOTES for the 2nd time. Last time, I switched from (lost) Huawei to Xiaomi and thought they were not restored because of that. This time, I restored my Redmi 10C data, stored on Google (not MiCloud) to Poco X5 Pro AND AGAIN LOST ALL NOTES including my notes for my book and financial data.
Does somebody know if I can FIND MY NOTES somewhere? My backup is 10 days old. I just restored it an hour ago (April 18, 2024).
I read that deleted notes can be restored for a couple of days.
Could maybe help if I wipe my phone via the Find My Device function when the thief charges it? Would they then be stored in the Google Cloud/MiCloud and could then be restored?

Sometimes manufacturers customize their Android, including built-in apps, and also Notes apps. Since data is linked to its app, only if it is the same app on both devices, then the data might be backed up and restored on Google Backup. However, I don't know if Huawei, Xiaomi, and Poco are using the same app for Notes (most likely not for Huawei, but not sure for Xiaomi and Poco). On the other hand, if manufacturers provide their backup services, then they usually contain backup data from their built-in apps. One thing, wiping the phone from Find My Device doesn't affect backup and restore.

If they are that important, then consider saving them on a USB stick, or an SD card.

You can try this:

Figure out the package name of the Notes app which you were using on your previous phone (Redmi).
Search for the app in Play Store or online.
Download the app and if it has an option to sign in to Google/Xiaomi account, do that.
See if the notes are restored. If not, see if the app has a restore from backup option.


Hi, unfortunately, this is not helpful at all.  Its just conjecture.  For point 4 to be useful, you need to explain how to do the restore.
